# Visual Studio 2017 - Xamarin - The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm fighting with that issue for 2 days already and can't find any solution.

I have an Xamarin Android app in Visual Studio 2017 consisting of three projects:

1. Xamarin.Android project (main one)
2. Android-specific unit tests run on the device - project of type `NUnit 3 Test Project (Android)` created using [NUnit Templates for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTemplatesforVisualStudio)
3. Platform-independent unit tests project (project of type `Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)`)

Everything worked just fine until now. When I selected my main project as the Startup one, my app was deployed to the device/emulator. When I selected my Android-specific unit tests project, the test project was deployed and unit tests executed by nUnit Xamarin Runners on the device/emulator.

However few days ago I updated my Visual Studio 2017 with the newest available update and now, when trying to build this android-specific unit tests project **I get the following error**:

`The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.`

I've searched everywhere, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292577/android-app-compile-not-generating-package-resources) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398188/xamarin-android-can-not-debug) SO topics. I also totally reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin with Android SDK included. Nothing helped. From what I read I suspect there is something wrong with the versions of *Android SDK Build-tools* I have installed. Here's what I have currently installed in SDK Manager:
[image]

As the other SO threads suggested, I tried uninstalling the newest *Android SDK Build-tools (25.0.2)* and installed version 23.0.3 (all my projects target Android 6.0), but it also doesn't help, I still have the same error.

Maybe it's worth adding that this issue may have started to happen when I tried to implement RecyclerView in my app reading [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) tutorial, where they suggested to install *Android 7.1.1 (API 25)* in SDK Manager. However I undoed my all changes after that and even reintalled VS2017 + Xamarin.

Do you have any other idea why this can be ? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

**EDIT 2017-04-09:**

Egh, I removed VS2017, installed VS2015 with brand new Android SDK and still the same issue :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've finally found what was the issue. It wasn't related to any component from SDK Manager or VS version.

Following [localization tutorial from developer.xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/localization/), I played a bit with `Strings.xml` in my Android project. I wanted to have my Activities Label taken from resources as well, so in the `ActivityAttribute` I defined:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/peopleListTitle")]
```

and added this value in `Strings.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-------Other resources values ----->
    <string name="peopleListTitle">People List</string>
</resources>
```

In that case my build is failing with above-mentioned error:

`The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist`

When I change `ActivityAttribute` to use a string directly:

```
[Activity(Label = "People List")]
```

the build is passing without any issues.

I managed to find a solution, but actually I don't know why it's not building when I try to use Label text defined in `Strings.xml`.

BTW, I managed to find what's the problem by setting build output verbosity to `Diagnostic` in *Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run* which gives a detailed info why the build failed in the Output window.

Comment: Yep. The **Diagnostic** option saved my life. In my case, the problem was caused by an image that I added into Resources/drawable folder with a dash in the name. I discovered that by turning on that Diagnostic option. Thanks @DawidSibinski!

Comment: A small invalid .axml tag chewed up a day for me too. Microsoft/Xamarin, please get intellisense working and make this better!

Comment: Still error :( You said "[Activity(Label = "People List")]" than the build is passing without any issues.

Hahaha you're liar! I have tried but I got error. :( like The file "obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources" How do I fix? Stop scamming us!

Comment: @SourceSkyBoxer hehe, you sound funny ;) Have you checked your build output with verbosity set to Diagnostic? If yes, paste the detailed error's contents here.

Comment: Thanks !! Diagnostic saved me also. My case was an invalid png file which I had renmed from jpg

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. After removing the dash "-" sign from the image file name, the problem is solved. Bad error message! It should not be:

> The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.

Writing an error message like this causing the Developer to think about something else while the problem is the illegal file name.

Comment: In addition to the "-", no name with accented graphical accents.

Comment: neither spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I added a new image as a resource. 
There was a '**`-`**' in the file name (*Invalid resource name character*). I renamed & removed that character and all good.
Resource name can only consist of 0-9,a-z or A-Z or combination of any.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and i removed all image file name have "-" character. My problem solved

Comment: Nice! After I removed the "-" character from my icon files, the real problem was detailed in my output window and this helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this error is that you may have a **float number** as your **version** number. In my case I changed it to a integer and everything worked fine. (I found the error by switching the **build output** to **Detailed**)

Answer (score 1):

Simply it worked.

1. In one case I copied and pasted previous working "packaged_resources"
   in the bin folder.[the problem was it did not reflect the UI changes]
2. Other I opened the visual studio as
   administrator.
3. Next changed the "Minimum target to Android" to lower
   apis in the project properties windows.
4. I suggest not touching the code behind of the design. If you get this error simply pull some button from the tool bar into the design and visual studio will come to its consciousness that there is change in UI. Next click on save all so that it make necessary change in the designer file.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a different solution (and only half a day lost): I was having trouble getting Hockey app to match crashes against the correct version of the app and realised it uses VersionCode not VersionName so I change my code to "0.0.34" the same as the name. For some still unknown reason the app built and deployed to devices for about 3 days before I started getting this error `The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.` Setting it back to a numeric value fixed the problem.

I found the problem by looking back through my GIT logs and rebuild each push until I found the one that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It just because the Version Code,I set Code by '1.0',*The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.*;And I set it by '1',everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, the way I got over it was crank up the Android SDK manager and install all updates and remove any obsolete packages.  This happened to me because I was targeting something newer which was not installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are any unused entries in resources.designer.cs if there are any manually remove those entries. 
This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After following several online suggestions - updating SDK, updating Xamarin etc - none of which worked for me.

Finally found that I had an activity for a Android provider to Alarm clock in my **AndroidManifest** file as below

```
 <activity 
     android:name="com.njcommuter.droid/android.provider.AlarmClock" 
     android:label="AlarmClock"
     .....
     />
```

Removing this line - and **rebuilding** worked fine without any errors and was able to deploy solution successfully.

> Note : testing this by putting the line back, and I get same error again on rebuilding.
>   It can be linked to using any android provider which creates the package for it, not necessarily AlarmClock only.

Answer (score 0):

This error is, somewhat of, a wrapper for what can be multiple reasons that that the file was not created.  The key is to look in the detailed output and look for the underlying error causing the file creation failure.

In my case, I had corrupted icon.png files (generated right from from the VS xamarin nunit template, no less!).  Once I put in valid png files, everything was built fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error, if that the android NDK (not android SDK) isn't right, change de version can resolve the problem: go to Tools/Options/Xamarin/android Configurator and change de folder, in my case I've three, the last one can't compile, but the second folder with version `xx.r11c` do it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Target Android Version.I had it set to

[image: Compile Version]

but changing it to Compiling version(for me it was the latest platform)  resolved the issue.

[image]