# How to get information about a failed build in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

After trying to change the names of the EditText in my app, I suddenly can't debug it anymore cause it keeps failing to build and I get this error `The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist`.

I've looked online and found that deleting the SDK sometimes helps, and others saw it was a completely different issue with files names or strings.

I ran across this StackOverflow thread where the user explains how he arrived at what the issue was using the diagnostic output in VS. I managed to get this far, but as a still learning programmer, the wall of text is overwhelming me and I'm not sure what I'm looking for to resolve my issue.

This is the thread I'm talking about - [Visual Studio 2017 - Xamarin - The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294345/visual-studio-2017-xamarin-the-file-obj-debug-android-bin-packaged-resource) (Look under the solution in the comments)

What should I be looking for in that output? I could probably upload mine and have someone point out the solution, but I'm hoping to learn from this so I can resolve similar issues when I run into them :)

Thanks!

Edit: When I double click on the error, it takes me to Xamarin.Android.Common.target, but doesn't highlight the issue so I'm still totally lost :/

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your solution? in Visual Studio go to View -> Output and select Show output from build.

Comment: I have, but the error is still there. So I can see a giant wall of text, and I'm sure the solution is there somewhere but I have no idea how to find it. I'd post a comment on the other thread but I don't have enough points to.

Comment: Can close and reopen VS also worth trying to delete obj/* folder in your android project

Comment: Those didn't work either

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions in the xamarin forum? (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63356/the-file-obj-debug-android-bin-packaged-resources-does-not-exist)

Comment: So it seems like André Luiz in that thread had the same issue I did, but I don't understand how to extract the error from that debug log. That's my issue. I know it will show me the error, but I can't figure out how to pinpoint it

Comment: @EladKarni can you copy-paste your build's output to some pastebin and put a link here ? Remember about setting build output verbosity to Diagnostic in Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run

Comment: I solved it! I put the error into the search box and there was only one instance of it showing up. After looking around for a few minutes I found an error saying that I had an issue with my margins!

Answer (score 0):

I have logged a bug on this here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55232

The issue is that the `AAPT` errors are not making it to the `Error List` in Visual Studio. I would suspect this is a bug immediately as the behavior was not present before this release.

The method to debug issues until this is hotfixed is to turn your MSBuild verbosity to `diagnostic` in your Visual Studio options. Next rebuild your project and search for `apt` or the `aapt` task in which you'll find the errors of your project.

If you want to upload a build output to your original post, I can push you in the right direction.